# How to write Subquery in Select statement laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How to write this query in laravel 5.1

```
SELECT 
     (SELECT firstname FROM registration_details a INNER JOIN users b 
        ON a.id = b.registerid
        WHERE c.patientid = b.id ) AS patient,
     (SELECT firstname FROM registration_details a INNER JOIN users b 
        ON a.id = b.registerid 
        WHERE c.doctorid = b.id ) AS doctor, 
    c.`appoinmentdate`
FROM `appoinments` c
```

I tried like this But i get Undefined property: stdClass::$id  error

```
 DB::table('appoinments')
   ->select(DB::raw(
       "(SELECT firstname FROM registration_details INNER JOIN users ON      registration_details.id = users.registerid WHERE appoinments.patientid =    users.id) AS patient",
       "(SELECT firstname FROM registration_details INNER JOIN users ON registration_details.id = users.registerid WHERE appoinments.doctorid = users.id) As doctor",
       "appoinments.appoinmentdate",
       "appoinments.id",
       "(SELECT timings FROM appoinment_time WHERE appoinment_time.id = appoinments.appoinment_time) AS apptime ",
       "(SELECT branchname FROM branches WHERE branches.id = appoinments.branchcode) AS branch"))
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer. Thanks to all who try for me.

```
$appoinment = DB::table('appoinments')->select(DB::raw("(SELECT firstname FROM registration_details INNER JOIN users ON registration_details.id = users.registerid WHERE appoinments.patientid = users.id) AS patientid"));
$appoinment = $appoinment->addSelect(DB::raw("(SELECT firstname FROM registration_details INNER JOIN users ON registration_details.id = users.registerid WHERE appoinments.doctorid = users.id) As doctorid"));
$appoinment = $appoinment->addSelect(DB::raw("appoinments.appoinmentdate"));
$appoinmentlist = $appoinment3->addSelect(DB::raw("appoinments.id"))->get();
```